# On Ubuntu remove linefeed \n but NOT return \r

Tags: csv, ubuntu-18.04

On Ubuntu I have the below input csv data where there are linefeeds that I need to remove but leave the carriage returns so that the records remain on separate lines. In notepad++ the LF and CRLF actually show :

```
"data","","AO1","AO1","9/30/2019 5:58:07 AM","data data","AO1","AO1","","","data","","","data","fndata","lndata","","datedata","data","653","datedata","","","data%","","","English","Expressive","","","","","","","9/30/2019","","","","","emdata","data","","","","","","","St.data","","citydata","data","zipdata","","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","","data","Lorem Ipsum data data  data

data data","","","","","","","9/30/2019 5:58:07 AM"
```

I've tried tr '\n' ' ' <   but this also removed the carriage returns
Also, have tried sed 's/\n//' which makes no change to the input file.

I've also attempted the code below in python which worked in windows but not on ubuntu

```
def replaceall(file, searchexp, replaceexp):
    backup = file + '.bak'
    os.rename(file,  backup)
    with open(backup, 'r', newline='') as source, open(file, 'w', newline='') as dest:
        for line in source:
            if searchexp in line:
                line = line.replace(searchexp, replaceexp)
            dest.write(line)
```

I would expect that this line would be on a single like and keep the carriage return intact.

Answer (score 0):

Realized after the fact that I can on Ubuntu use the above python code to replace the \n with space then rerun and replace the \r with \r\n and have the file cleaned.

Sorry for the noise but hope it helps someone else out.